# iOS stream playback with AVPlayer don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem

I play video streams with AVPlayer.

Some of streams plays only if click button "Play" for 2-5 times. (sorry, I can't provide link, and don't sure what especial in this streams, but may be problem only with full hd streams)

I do like that:

fields:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
AVPlayer *player;
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.player = player;
```

when click "Play":

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

[playerItem addObserver:self
    forKeyPath:@"status"
    options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
    context:nil];  

[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

and observing:

```
NSLog(@"status changed");
if (((AVPlayerItem *)object).status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
{
    NSLog(@"ready to play");
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [player play];
}
else if (((AVPlayerItem *)object).status == AVPlayerStatusFailed)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to ready");
}
else if (((AVPlayerItem *)object).status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown)
{
    NSLog(@"unknown");
}
```

First always "unknown" but in problem cases no messages after (but most streams play normally and I see "ready to play" message)

I've tried to observe `player.status` but when it ReadyToPlay and I start play I see only first frame and endless message "Loading" in top of screen.

Comment: if you want to use third party then this is the best lib https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer

Comment: thx, i'll try this